# Android - Unknown memory leak in a very light app

Tags: android

I'm writing a very simple "contacts" application. For now, I just have a ListView and next to each name is an image. There are only 20 contacts and each image averages about 4.5kb, so there's no way I should be reaching the app's memory limit upon starting it. I'm not sure where the issue is, but I'm guessing it's in the code that generates the rows.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.topLine);
    TextView phone = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    name.setText(contactArray.get(position).getName());
    phone.setText((CharSequence) contactArray.get(position).getPhone().getWorkPhone());
    new ImageDownloader(icon).execute(contactArray.get(position).getImageURL());

    return row;
}
```

The problem will go away if I comment out the to lines relating to my ImageView. Why would those lines take up more memory than necessary?

Comment: are you getting memory leak or out of memory error?

Comment: I'm actually getting neither. But I get a bunch of GC_Concurrent calls about freeing up space. I feel like the Garbage Collector shouldn't be called this much for a program that's so light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inflating an xml layout for each view instead of recycling existing views. Inflating a layout is an expensive operation (in memory) so you could start there.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
}

TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Position " + position);

return convertView;
```

}

Then use the ViewHolder pattern

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText("Position " + position);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
}
```

Source: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/